# Perform GET and POST request using same controller function in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on developing a web page with AngularJS and Java. I'm consuming a REST service to get a Map of checklist description as :

```
{checklist:{'sample1': true, 'sample2': false, 'sample3': true}}
```

My controller is as follows :

```
angular.module('checklist.controllers',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','CheckFactory', function ($scope,CheckFactory) {
  CheckFactory.query({}, function (data){
    $scope.sample=data.checklist;
  });
}]);
```

and my service :

```
angular.module('checklist.services',['ngResource'])
factory('CheckFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('#myRESTendpoint', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', params:{} }
  });
}]);
```

I have configured my `app.js` accordingly and my HTML :

```
<label ng-repeat="(key,data) in sample"> 
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sample[key]"/>
  {{key}}
  <br/>
</label>
```

Everything works fine and I get a checklist of values checked whenever the value of the map is true. But, is there a way I can enhance the current implementation to POST a request to update if I change the existing 'false' values of checkbox to 'true' in the same page and post it to the rest service without redirecting it to a new page with another controller for update?

Please provide some inputs or resources links which can help me find a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using $resource, you can use 'return $http.post(yourendpointURL)' in your service. After that in your controller use deferred method e.g. `.then(function(response){ $scope.data = response.data; })`

Add an ngClick to your input[checkbox] to call a function in your controller that calls the $http service to update your data.

Comment: Couldn't quite get your answer. I started working on angular from past 4 days and I'm trying to get a checklist object which has a map of values with key as description and value true/false. I would like to populate the checkboxes as checked based on the value it already has and if an update is performed and submitted it updates the existing object via a post request using the REST service. I'm using angularJS and backend as Java. Couldn't quite get any leads on how this can be implemented. Can you elaborate on your response with an example atleast?